# AWS Lambda HTTP 503 when opening amazon urls

Tags: python, http, aws-lambda, urllib, http-status-code-503

Hello I developed an AWS Lambda which makes an http request to amazon url to get the web page content.
The problem I have regards the HTTP 503 error I get every time I run the lambda. Running the code locally it works fine but on AWS it doesn't.

I am using `Python 3.7` and `urllib` module

Below the source code

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.amazon.it/dp/B0786QNS9B'
reqq = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'})
reddit_file = urllib.request.urlopen(reqq)
```

I changed several times the `User-agent` value but it doesn't work.

I was wondering if the problem could be related to the IP address used by my AWS account when I run the lambda, I checked what's the IP used every time and I see it's always the same, so basically it's a static ip address.

I'm not using the API Gateway service, just the lambda only.

Is it possible to use a different IP address for each run of the lambda function?
Will this solve my issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is the request returning 503 or the Lambda? What does the CloudWatch logs say?

Comment: the cloudwatch logs shows the error `[ERROR] 2023-10-19T10:58:36.034Z a9f74950-aeb1-4bb6-ad0e-44a0d99a446d HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable`

The problem occurs only accessing amazon uri, if I use another url the lambda works properly

Comment: 'amazon uri' - do you mean function URL?

Comment: I mean URL, like the one I posted above in the code